# What is the best way to define styling? Class names or relative path?

Tags: css

I joined a new project this week and I noticed that the designer (who creates all .css files) uses css in a different way of what I am used to.
I am used to have mainly the elemented referenced by classes and classes names, for instance have a definition

```
.myClass { display:block; }
```

and use the `class="myClass"` attribute in my element.

this designer builds the whole design using this kind of reference:

```
form#myForm div a { display:block; }
```

Or similar. This would get the all the anchors inside divs inside the form where id=myForm.

Which one is the best approach? Mainly using classes or mainly using this other approach (I don't know how to call it)?

thanks!

Comment: if your style can be applied to all the elements in the div that match then save yourself a class and use the one the designer uses. If you may have 2 or 3 elements that match but are exceptions then use a class. Depends on how specific you need to get

Comment: Just a suggestion : **don't** argue with designers. Even if it is obvious, **don't** argue with designers.

Comment: CSS selectors should be long enough to select the correct element, and no longer. `form#myForm div a` has a high specificity, which makes it more difficult to override, and that makes the entire stylesheet harder to maintain. I recently started using [Nicolas Gallagher's take on BEM syntax](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), and I've found it to be much easier to manage so far.

Comment: [CSS Specificity for Poker Players](http://iamacamera.org/default.aspx?id=95) is a good read. How you define your selectors and the order they are written in _do_ matter.

Comment: The first approach (class names) is more flexible and makes the styles easier to re-use. It also requires more engineering skill to apply it consistently and correctly. The second approach (relative paths) might be safer for people with very little front-end experience or very little technical ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something that nobody has included in their answers yet, oddly enough and that is it all depends on how specific you want / need to be in your selections.

## The basics:

If you want to select multiple elements on a page, simply using a class selector will work:

```
.non-unique-elements{
    // some style
}
```

If you want to get somewhat more specific, or want to select a *unique* element on the page, go with an `ID` selector:

```
#unique-element{
    // some style
}
```

## Further Styling

Now, as your coleague has done, you can get even more specific by selecting an element's `ID` only when it has other attributes; for example, you may want to select all elements that contain a certain class name, but are also of type `form`

```
form.some-class{
    // style
}
```

## The most selective CSS will override less selective CSS

Therefore, consider the following example:

```
.some-class{

}
```

Gets overridden by:

```
#some-id{

}
```

Gets overridden by

```
div#some-id{

}
```

Comment: The problem is that the same selector applies to different pages. And changing one affects all of them and changing the HTML breaks everything. It is driving me crazy <o>

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the purpose.
Class should be used to define general style where as ID should be used to select a specific item.

Answer (score 0):

it's a question of whether of the css properties you're writing depends on the relationship between the html tag and its parents (and siblings):

to illustrate,

i want to set the color of **some** text in the page to red -> use Only Classes `.redtext`

i want to set the color of **some** text **only** in specifics div -> `.mydiv .redtext`

i want to set the width of **all** inputs **only in a specific** form -> `#myform input`

keep in mind that using long css selectors make them very dependent on the Page structure and therefore fragile.